# How to add frame boxes around all equations?

Tags: equations

How to add frame boxes to all equations in a LaTeX file, to make all the equations seems like

[image]

which can be obtained by

```
\[\boxed{a+b}\]
```

For example, transform this

[image]

into this

[image]

As far as I know, there are many types of equation environments in LaTeX. Such as

```
$a+b$, 

\[a+b\]

\begin{equation}
    a+b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
    a+b
\end{equation*}

\begin{eqnarray}
    a+b \\
    c+d
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}
    a+b \\  
    c+d
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
    \left(
    \begin{matrix}
        a &b \\
        c &d
    \end{matrix}
    \right)
\end{equation}
```

And so on ...

So, is there any magic method to add bounding boxes to all these equation environments **without change the code of equations**? I mean **DO NOT** modify the code of equations one by one, just like

```
$\boxed{a+b}$

\[\boxed{a+b}\]

\begin{equation}
    \boxed{a+b}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
    \boxed{a+b}
\end{equation*}

\begin{eqnarray}
    \boxed{a+b} \\
    \boxed{c+d}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}
    \boxed{a+b} \\
    \boxed{c+d}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{
    \left(
    \begin{matrix}
        a &b \\
        c &d
    \end{matrix}
    \right)
}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Did you search Google for "boxed equation latex"? Or what do you mean with "bounding box"? I understand that you just want "boxed"?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have improved the problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(rewrote answer to let it handle multi-line math environments of `amsmath` package)

The following solution, which requires LuaLaTeX, handles inline math cases as well as single-line display-math environments such as `equation`, `equation*`, and `displaymath`. It also handles four of the  multi-line equation environments of `amsmath` package -- `align`, `alignat`, `gather`, and `multline`, plus their "starred" variants -- with the caveat that any equation numbers are suppressed. (The only major standalone multi-line equation environment that's not automatically boxed is the `flalign` environment, and its starred cousin.)

The code provides two user-level LaTeX macros: `\EqboxOn` and `\EqboxOff`. The former turns on automatic boxing, and the latter turns it off. The Lua function that's enabled by `\EqboxOn` scans all input lines and inserts `\boxed` statements "on the fly", as needed. Note that the definitions of the math environments are not modified.

Observe that no code is provided to handle `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` environments. This omission is deliberate: These environments are deprecated and should no longer be used.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function eq_boxed ( s )   
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\%[)"       , "%1\\boxed{" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\%])"       , "}%1" )
  s = s:gsub ( "%$%$(.-)%$%$" , "\\[\\boxed{%1}\\]" ) -- $$ .. $$ 
  s = s:gsub ( "%$(.-)%$"     , "$\\boxed{%1}$" )     -- inline math
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\begin{displaymath})" , "%1\\boxed{" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\end{displaymath})"   , "}%1" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\begin{equation%*?})" , "%1\\boxed{" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\end{equation%*?})"   , "}%1" )
  -----
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\begin{align%*?})"    , "\\[\\boxed{\\begin{aligned}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\end{align%*?})"      , "\\end{aligned}}\\]" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\begin{alignat%*?})"  , "\\[\\boxed{\\begin{alignedat}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\end{alignat%*?})"    , "\\end{alignedat}}\\]" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\begin{gather%*?})"   , "\\[\\boxed{\\begin{gathered}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\end{gather%*?})"     , "\\end{gathered}}\\]" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\begin{multline%*?})" , "\\[\\boxed{\\begin{multlined}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(\\end{multline%*?})"   , "\\end{multlined}}\\]" )
return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}
%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\EqboxOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", eq_boxed, "eq_boxed" )}}
\newcommand\EqboxOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "eq_boxed" )}}

\begin{document}
\EqboxOn % turn on automatic boxing

$a+b$, $e^{i\pi}-1=0$

\[a+b\]

\[
c+d
\]

$$e+f$$

\begin{equation}
    g+h
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
    a^b+b^2=c^2
\end{equation*}

\begin{displaymath}
    1+1=2
\end{displaymath}

\begin{align}
    E   &= mc^2 \\
    b^2 &= a^2+2\int_a^b x\,dx
\end{align}

\begin{gather}
     d = e + f \\ 
     g = h + i + j + k
\end{gather}

\begin{multline*}
  d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n\\
     =o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z
\end{multline*}

\begin{alignat}{2}
x &= y_1-y_2+y_3-y_5+y_8-\dotsb&\quad& \text{by abc}\\
  &= y'\circ y^*                    && \text{by def}\\
  &= y(0) y'                        && \text {by Axiom 1.}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice answer! But I have a question: for this method based on string replacement,  does it works for user defined macros, such as `\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}` and `\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}`. I am not confident that I can consider all possible mathematical environments.

Comment: @余江涛 - The preprocessor-based appoach proposed in this answer operates on the input at a very early stage, i.e., *before* TeX starts its usual work of macro expansion, etc. Hence, the Lua function `eq_boxed` will "see" just `\be` and `\ee`, *not* `\begin{equation}` and `end{equation}`. It will therefore not perform any `\boxed` insertions for equations marked off with `\be` and `\ee` (or any other user-defined macros). Aside: providing such abbreviations doesn't work anyway for the multi-line equation environments of the `amsmath` package.